# Mysql JOIN query MAX value

Tags: mysql

This is example of the problem i am having. The query should return rows `paul` and `rick` because they have the highest rating of the child rows.  Instead the query is returning `dave` and `owen`, my guess is because they are the first child rows.  I am grouping by `position` and using `MAX(child.rating)` but the query isn't working like i want it to be.  In the real table i have alot of columns that is why i use `child.*` in the select clause.

mytable

```
  id |  name | parentid|  position| rating  |
   1 |  mike |    1    |    1     |    6    |
   2 |  dave |    1    |    2     |    5    |
   3 |  paul |    1    |    2     |    7    |
   4 |  john |    1    |    2     |    3    |
   5 |  mike |    5    |    1     |    8    |
   6 |  owen |    5    |    2     |    2    |
   7 |  rick |    5    |    2     |    9    |
   8 |  jaye |    5    |    2     |    3    |



$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(child.rating),child.* FROM mytable child 
        LEFT JOIN mytable parent on parent.parentid=child.parentid 
        WHERE parent.name LIKE '%mike%' GROUP BY child.position,child.parentid");



while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)) {

 $id = $row['id'];
 $name = $row['name'];
 $parentid = $row['parentid'];



if($id==$parentid) {
    continue;
    }
echo "<p>Name: $name </p>";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny thing, I've just realized what you're looking for. Here is the final query:

```
select t1.* from mytable t1
left join mytable t2
on t1.parentid = t2.parentid and t1.rating < t2.rating
join mytable parents
on parents.id = t1.parentid
where t2.rating is null and parents.name like '%mike%'
```

And here is a [working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97e60/2)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a subquery in from clause to first figure out what is the maximum rating for each parent and then get the children with that rating:

```
select * 
from mytable c
join 
   (select parentid, max(rating) as 'maxrating'
    from mytable m
    group by parentid) as q on c.parentid=q.parentid and c.rating = q.maxrating;
```

Comment: The subquery in the from is the need, exactly

Answer (score 0):

add:

```sql
ORDER BY child.rating DESC
```

Comment: i did it still is returning dave and owen

Comment: why you are doing group by position? it should work without that or try to group by rating

Answer (score 0):

This is the way mysql's group by works, and is actually working correctly.

There are two way around it, either a subquery or joins that get the top most child, and you probably want to reorder the way your tables are

Here's the join method (if i'm understanding your data correctly):

```
SELECT child.* 
FROM mytable parent 
LEFT JOIN mytable child ON parent.parentid=child.parentid 
LEFT JOIN mytable child2 ON child.parentid=child2.parentid AND child2.rating > child.rating AND child2.parentid IS NULL 
WHERE parent.name LIKE '%mike%' AND parent.position = 1 AND child.position <> 1
```

This makes the assumption that parants always have a position of 1, and children do not.  You may need to also add another bit to the child2 join to remove the possibility of parents having a higher rating than the children?

The 2nd join makes sure there are no other children with a higher rating for each parent.

Answer (score 0):

This must be what you're trying to do (although I'm unsure if're really comparing child's parentid with parent's parentid):

```
SELECT child.* FROM mytable child 
    INNER JOIN mytable parent on parent.parentid=child.parentid 
    LEFT JOIN mytable child2 ON (child2.parentid = parent.parentid AND child2.position = child.position AND child2.rating > child.rating)
    WHERE parent.name LIKE '%mike%' AND child2.parentid IS NULL
    GROUP BY child.position, child.parentid
    HAVING `better` = 0;
```

Another option would be to use a subquery, but you should check which works faster:

```
SELECT child.*
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(child.rating) maxrating, child.parentid, child.position FROM mytable child 
        INNER JOIN mytable parent on parent.parentid=child.parentid 
        WHERE parent.name LIKE '%mike%'
        GROUP BY child.position,child.parentid
) h
    INNER JOIN mytable child ON (child.parentid = h.parentid AND child.position = h.position AND child.rating = h.maxrating)
```

performance may be very different on tables of different sizes.

If I haven't got your point right, I still suggest you use INNER JOINs instead of OUTERs if you don't need anything for which there's nothing to join. INNER JOINs are usually way faster.

I actually think second one will work faster on larger tables.